# Зацикливание из за игнорирования scanf

Tags: c

Имеется вот такой код:

```
int main() {

    int menu = 0;
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int check = -1;
    for (int i = 0, k = 1; i < k; i++, k++) {
        scanf("%d*c", &menu);
        if (menu == 1) {
            if (check != -1) {
                free(name);
                name = malloc(sizeof(char));
            }
            name = read_str(name);
            check = case_1(name);
        } else if (menu == 2) {
            case_2(name);
            if (check != -1) {
                case_1(name);
            }
        } else if (menu == -1) {
            i = k;
        } else {
            printf("n/a\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Функции не очень важны, только этот цикл for. То есть должно работать только при вводе 1, 2 или -1. Если ввожу другое число, все отрабатывает нормально,  один раз печатается n/a и цикл идет заново и позволяет вводить следующее число. Однако если я введу не число, а какую-нибудь букву, просто начинается бесконечный спам n/a. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Проверьте значение, которое возвращает `scanf`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char))` - всегда ошибка.

Comment: В смысле ошибка? Вроде не было никаких проблем с маллоком. Да и на scanf оно же никак не влияет.

Comment: дизайн этой функции онда сплошная ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Сразу бросается в глаза, вы мало выделяете память, всего один байт постоянно. `sizeof(char) == 1` Выделяйте память побольше.
При считывании числа запись `"%d*c"` у меня никак не работает, даже когда лишние буквы идут в конце. И функция `scanf` возвращает всегда количество считанных аргументов ноль.
Решением вашей проблемы будет контролировать возвращаемое значение и при возникновении проблем очищать буфер потока с помощью считывании всей оставшейся строки букв.

```
enum {STRSIZE = 840};
char *name = malloc(sizeof(char)*STRSIZE);
...
do {
      int sr = scanf("%d", &menu);
      if (sr == 0) {
        fgets ( name , STRSIZE , stdin ) ;
        menu = -7 ;
        fputs("Неправильно заведено число\n",stderr);
      }
} while ( menu != -7 ) ;
```